# Magento filter showing mode,order,limit in url

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have used Magento 1.9  I have to get problem in Magento filtered navigation.  When I click filtered navigation then getting the wrong URL

Correct url:

[http: // localhost/ Magento/bathroom/bathroom-sink-and-faucet/ceramic-sink.html?cat=205](http://http:%20//%20localhost/%20Magento/bathroom/bathroom-sink-and-faucet/ceramic-sink.html?cat=205)

Wrong url:

[http: //localhost/ Magento/bathroom/bathroom-sink-and-faucet/ceramic-sink.html?p=1&dir=asc&limit=21& mode=grid& order=bestseller &cat=205](http://http:%20//localhost/%20Magento/bathroom/bathroom-sink-and-faucet/ceramic-sink.html?p=1&dir=asc&limit=21&%20mode=grid&%20order=bestseller%20&cat=205)

I don't know why it's showing many filters in URL.previously it's showing one but now it's showing many. Please give suggestions.

Comment: by any chance did you filter or sorted the search results previously? try clearing the session and/or the cookies.

Comment: @marius Not any changed in filter and sorted .........